# show this $\{m\sqrt[n]{a}\}>\frac{c}{m^{n-2}}$

Tags: approximation

Prove or disprove

> let $n>4$ be  give postive integers,if $a$ is also be give postive integers,such  $\sqrt[n]{a}$ be not postive integers,show that: for any postive $m$,there exist constant $c$,such
>   $$\{m\sqrt[n]{a}\}>\dfrac{c}{m^{n-2}}$$
>   where $\{x\}=x-[x]$

My try: let $[m\sqrt[n]{a}]=k$,then $m\sqrt[n]{a}>k$,so we have
$$m^n\cdot a-k^n\ge 1$$
so we have
$$\{m\sqrt[n]{a}\}=(m\sqrt[n]{a}-k)\ge\dfrac{1}{(m\sqrt[n]{a})^{n-1}+(m\sqrt[n]{a})^{n-2}k+\cdots+k^{n-1}}>\dfrac{1}{n(m(\sqrt[n]{a})^{n-1}}=\dfrac{c}{m^{n-1}}$$
where $c=\dfrac{1}{n(\sqrt[n]{a})^{n-1}}$
But I can't prove the $LHS>\dfrac{c}{m^{n-2}}$

Comment: Recall [Liouville's theorem on algebraic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence), it will lead to $n-1$ exponent as well. Where did you find this problem? Maybe there is a typo in the text.

Comment: can you prove the $n-2$ is hold?